# cannot connect to database from custom docker workspace for laravel -> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: mysql, laravel

I try to setup docker workspace for laravel on my synology NAS.
But have `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = projectdb and table_name = admin_config and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`  error on web page.

1. I setup `mariadb+adminer+nginx+php:7.4-fpm` in one docker network.

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  mariadb: 
    image: mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      TZ: ${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/dump:/dump
      - ./mysql/logs:/var/log/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306 # Initially I don't have that. Just add for debugging on step 4.
    networks:
      - internal


  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: adminer
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - internal


  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      TZ: ${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx/
      - ${PROJECTS}:/var/www
      - ${SSL_CERT_PROJECT1}:/etc/ssl/private/project1.lan
      - ${PROJECTS}/project1.lan/storage/app/public/:/var/www/project1.lan/public/storage/
    ports:
      - 82:80
      - 444:443
    networks:
      - internal


  php: 
    container_name: php
    build:
      context: ./php
    working_dir: /var/www
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=192.168.220.1 remote_enable=1"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
      TZ: ${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
    volumes:
      - ./.ssh:/home/www-data/.ssh
      - ${PROJECTS}:/var/www
    extra_hosts:
      - 'project1.lan:192.168.1.2' 
      - 'project2.lan:192.168.1.2' 
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:
    name: webserver
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.220.0/28
```

.env for docker-compose

```
DB_DATABASE=server
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=123456
WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE=Europe/Moscow
PROJECTS=/volume1/web
SSL_CERT_PROJECT1=/usr/syno/etc/certificate/_archive/LZ4CDy
```

nginx Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
RUN mkdir -p /etc/ssl/private/project1.lan
WORKDIR /var/www
```

php Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget git nano unzip imagemagick nodejs npm \
    libpq-dev libicu-dev libpng-dev libzip-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.9.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pgsql 

ADD ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/installer -O - -q \
    | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer --quiet


WORKDIR /var/www
```

It is working. I tested with phpinfo file in project1.lan folder.

2. I copied my laravel folder `project1.lan` from laptop (I use laragon now for local development) to `/volume1/web` on Synology.
3. I did export of `projectdb` database and imported it using Adminer under root user. First I tried as simple `user`, but I got access rights error during import and I switched to `root`.
4. in laravel .env file I put this, because I expect that it is handled by php from my container in the same network and should understand where `mariadb` located

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=projectdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

And then on web page I see connection error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

Trying to understand how to solve that I tried to map port 3306 outside of container and trying to put these values in .env file for laravel

```
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_HOST=localhost
```

But result always the same.

I also tried to do

```
docker-compose exec "php" php project1.lan/artisan config:cache
docker-compose exec "php" php project1.lan/artisan config:clear
```

But again I just see `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` in terminal.

5. Then I tried to connect to mariadb using adminer using 127.0.0.1 or localhost or http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1.
   But I always got `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]`.

Finally I found only 2 options how to connect to mariadb via Adminer.
First is `server=mariadb`.
Second is `server=192.168.1.2` when port 3306 mapped outside of mariadb container.
But anyway `DB_HOST=192.168.1.2` doesn't work inside laravel .env file.

My opinion that the problem is that Laravel simply doesn't see sql database, but I have no more idea how to debug it and find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have grants in your DB for the IP address of your database's container (even if it's 127.0.0.1, as opposed to just 'localhost').

Comment: Here is screenshot from adminer https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2oqz/4dqjSVNAx I think this means all privilegies.

Comment: Here is the result of `SHOW GRANTS;` command in terminal

**| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------                              ---------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '....' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION**

Comment: I can't remember offhand if `%` is sufficient, or if you actually need a record that specifies the IP address. Shouldn't hurt to add one though, just to see.

Comment: I just checked with simple php script `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);` and it works. So the problem should be somewhere inside laravel